# Using 2 tables in a View in ASP.Net MVC (Returning 2 LINQ using different models?)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, view, html-table

I have a `View` that needs to display, for example, a `User` and a `Role` table. I need to create 2 `LINQ` queries to be returned in the View, one for the `User` and the other one for the `Role` so that I can display 2 tables in the view. So far, I can only return the `User`, but how do I return also the `Role`? Here's my current setup:

**UserModel**

-The `ViewModel` is being used in View's textboxes and the `Model` for the looping of records in the table

```
public class UserModel
    {
        public int user_id { get; set; }
        public string user_name { get; set; }
        ...
    }
```

**UserViewModel**

```
public class UserViewModel
    {
        public IPagedList<CDS.Models.UserModel> Users { set; get; }
        public int userId { get; set; }
        public string userName { get; set; }
        ...
    }
```

**View**

```
@model CDS.Models.UserViewModel
@using PagedList.Mvc;

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "User", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.userId)
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.userName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.userName)

    <table id="dbTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="hidden">
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.user_id)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.ActionLink("User", "Create", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.UserSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="dbBody">
            @foreach (var item in Model.Users)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td class="hidden">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.user_id)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.user_name)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>

    //Don't mind this code, it's only for the pagination
    Page @(Model.Users.PageCount < Model.Users.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.Users.PageNumber) of @Model.Users.PageCount
    @Html.PagedListPager(Model.Users, page => Url.Action("Create",
    new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))
}
```

**UserController** - How can I return a `ViewModel` with another `LINQ` for the Role?

```
DBEntities _odb = new DBEntities();

public ActionResult Create(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
{

    var user = from u in _odb.USR_MSTR
                      select new UserModel
                      {
                          user_id  = u.USR_ID,
                          user_name  = u.USR_NAME,
                      };

    int pageSize = 10;
    int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

    var vm = new UserViewModel();
    vm.Users = user.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);

    return View(vm);
}
```

Comment: You start off saying you want to display a `Role` table, but then you ask about returning a `Region`?

Comment: I use `PartialView` for the display of records, I just didn't include it here to avoid long post. I'm thinking of using 2 `PartialView` for each table but not sure how do I return 2 `ViewModels` with different `LINQ`

Comment: @StephenMuecke oh shoot! Actually it's a different table in my current project, I just use a sample table here in my post. I'll edit it right away, thanks!

Comment: But `Role` has a FK to user, so surely you want to display the roles for each user, not a separate list of roles?

Comment: Oh, sorry for that. Looks like I should have not said that to avoid confusion. I'll just remove it. Let's just say I want the `User` and the `Role` be displayed in the same `View`.

Comment: But do you mean your want to display a table with 3 columns - the users ID, Name and a (say) a comma separated list of their roles, or do you want 2 separate tables?

Comment: I need 2 separate tables

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123493/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-philip-sy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options you can consider.

Add an additional property in you view model for the collection of `Role`

```
public IEnumerable<Role> Roles { get; set; }
```

and in the GET method

```
var roles = db.Roles..... // your query
var vm = new UserViewModel()
{
    Roles = roles,
    Users = user.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize)
};
return View(vm);
```

Or create a ChildActionOnly method that returns a partial view of your roles

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult FetchRoles()
{
    var model = ... // your query
    return PartialView(model);
}
```

and in `FetchRoles.cshtml`

```
@model IEnumerable<Role>
... // html to display roles
```

then in the main view, render it using

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("FetchRoles", "yourControllerName"); }
```

Comment: I did the first one since it's more familiar to me than the 2nd one, it worked! Thanks man! :)

Comment: The second one would be more appropriate if you wanted to reuse the partial view for Roles in other pages.